# pyspark databricks code to do zero byte check on incoming files

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

how to do audit checks on incoming files in data bricks.
wanted python code to do zero bytes check (should check if the file has data or not), if the file has data then it should continue with the process or else it should stop the process and email.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks has [dbutils.fs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#ls-command-dbutilsfsls) that returns a list of files from a directory, including file size. You can use that information to check per your use cases.